# Spring boot 2.7.9 - The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle restTemplate

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot application version 2.7.9. While creating restTemplate from RestTemplateBuilder , I'm getting the following exception:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

???->???
|  srGroupController (field org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.example.demo.SrGroupController.restTemplate)
???<-???



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/srgrp/")
public class SrGroupController {    
        
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jiraRT")
    RestTemplate restTemplate;  
    
    @Bean(name = "jiraRT")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.basicAuthentication("myuser", "paswword").build();
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping (value = "ping", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String ping() {  
        
        return "ping works!";       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add static modifier to restTemplate method

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate config class and define **RestTemplate** bean keep off from SrGroupController:

```
@Bean(name = "jiraRT")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.basicAuthentication("myuser", "paswword").build();
}
```

Now create a constructor and use **@Lazy** annotation:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public SrGroupController(
        @Lazy RestTemplate restTemplate
) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

Hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

add this in your application.properties file.

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references:true
```

If you are using application.yml then

```
spring:
   main:
    allow-circular-references: true
```

You can also use `@lazy`
`@lazy` will break the cycle dependency ask Spring to initialise one of the bean lazily. it will create a proxy to inject it into the other bean. The injected bean will only be fully created when it’s first needed.

you can choose any one of them, I would prefer do less cyclic dependency as much as possible, as it is impacting performance when application startup. I prefer to choose `@lazy` over `allow-circular-references: true`